# Docker Keycloak Mysql volume doesn't persist data

Tags: mysql, docker

I am trying to use keycloak and mysql containers to save users accessing my website. My docker-compose.yml file currently looks like this:

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.34
    container_name: mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=keycloak
      - MYSQL_USER=keycloak
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root_password
    healthcheck:
      test: "mysqladmin ping -u root -p$${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
      start_period: 10s
    volumes:
      - ./mysqldata:/var/log/mysql
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:14.0.0
    container_name: keycloak
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin
      - DB_VENDOR=mysql
      - DB_ADDR=mysql
      - DB_USER=keycloak
      - DB_PASSWORD=password
      - JDBC_PARAMS=useSSL=false
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    healthcheck:
      test: "curl -f http://localhost:8080/auth || exit 1"
      start_period: 20s
volumes:
  mysqldata:
```

(Obviously, the passwords would be changed before heading into produciton).

My problem is that no matter what I do I can't get the data made through the keycloak UI persist itself between docker-compose up and down commands. Making a new user for example makes its way into the database, but after restarting the containers the user is gone. Checking the volume folders on the host machine and inside the container show empty folders.

Comment: Found any solution? Still facing in Keycloak 20! 

Comment: No unfortunatelly, I didn't find a solution :(

Comment: I wonder how people using it. :/

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue using Keycloak 20.0.1 It seems like the environment variables do not work as expected any more. I had to pass the database specifications directly to the argument, otherwise the local h2 database was used.

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.34
    container_name: mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=keycloak
      - MYSQL_USER=keycloak
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root_password
    healthcheck:
      test: "mysqladmin ping -u root -p$${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
      start_period: 10s
    volumes:
      - ./mysqldata:/var/log/mysql
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:20.0.1
    container_name: keycloak
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin
      - JDBC_PARAMS=useSSL=false
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    command:
      - "start"
      - "--db mysql"
      - "--db-password password"
      - "--db-username keycloak"
      - "--db-url-host mysql"
      - "--db-url-database keycloak"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    healthcheck:
      test: "curl -f http://localhost:8080/auth || exit 1"
      start_period: 20s
volumes:
  mysqldata:
```

The other environment variables like KEYCLOAK_USER worked however.

I hope this helps even so it is a bit late.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I found the culprit.
I just changed all the `=`s to `:` in my `docker-compose.yml` file and used `KC_DB_URL` with full JDBC url and it worked.
But I ultimately chose to use `.env` file instead.

Here's the original compose file without env:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak
    container_name: keycloak
    environment:
       KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
       KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
       KC_PROXY: edge
       KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: false
       KC_HTTP_ENABLED: true
       KC_DB: postgres
       KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/keycloak_test
       KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak_test
       KC_DB_PASSWORD: keycloak_test
    volumes:
      - ./themes:/opt/keycloak/themes
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    command:
      - "start-dev"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl -f http://localhost:8080/realms/master"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloak_test
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: keycloak_test
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak_test
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U keycloak_test"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

And with `.env` file:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak
    container_name: keycloak
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./themes:/opt/keycloak/themes
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    command:
      - "start-dev"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl -f http://localhost:8080/realms/master"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloak_test
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: keycloak_test
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak_test
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U keycloak_test"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

The `.env` file:

```
KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
KC_PROXY=edge
KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT=false
KC_HTTP_ENABLED=true
KC_DB=postgres
KC_DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/keycloak_test
KC_DB_USERNAME=keycloak_test
KC_DB_PASSWORD=keycloak_test
```